# module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame' - suddenly all pandas attributes are not working in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am  trying to do a very simple pd.DataFrame(dict) which used to work before, not sure what I have done but none of pandas functions seem to be working. I uninstalled and re-installed pandas but to no avail.

Here is the code I am trying to write to get option chains:

```
import pandas as pd
dict = {'Contract': ['SPY211129C00320000', 'SPY211129C00345000', 'SPY211129C00355000', 'SPY211129C00365000', 'SPY211129C00370000', 'SPY211129C00385000', 'SPY211129C00395000', 'SPY211129C00400000', 'SPY211129C00405000', 'SPY211129C00410000', 'SPY211129C00412000', 'SPY211129C00413000', 'SPY211129C00414000', 'SPY211129C00415000', 'SPY211129C00416000', 'SPY211129C00418000', 'SPY211129C00419000', 'SPY211129C00420000', 'SPY211129C00421000', 'SPY211129C00422000', 'SPY211129C00423000', 'SPY211129C00425000', 'SPY211129C00426000', 'SPY211129C00428000', 'SPY211129C00429000', 'SPY211129C00430000', 'SPY211129C00431000', 'SPY211129C00432000', 'SPY211129C00433000', 'SPY211129C00434000', 'SPY211129C00435000', 'SPY211129C00436000', 'SPY211129C00437000', 'SPY211129C00438000', 'SPY211129C00439000', 'SPY211129C00440000', 'SPY211129C00441000', 'SPY211129C00442000', 'SPY211129C00443000', 'SPY211129C00444000', 'SPY211129C00445000', 'SPY211129C00446000', 'SPY211129C00447000', 'SPY211129C00448000', 'SPY211129C00449000', 'SPY211129C00450000', 'SPY211129C00451000', 'SPY211129C00452000', 'SPY211129C00453000', 'SPY211129C00454000', 'SPY211129C00455000', 'SPY211129C00456000', 'SPY211129C00457000', 'SPY211129C00458000', 'SPY211129C00459000', 'SPY211129C00460000', 'SPY211129C00461000', 'SPY211129C00462000', 'SPY211129C00463000', 'SPY211129C00464000', 'SPY211129C00465000', 'SPY211129C00466000', 'SPY211129C00467000', 'SPY211129C00468000', 'SPY211129C00469000', 'SPY211129C00470000', 'SPY211129C00471000', 'SPY211129C00472000', 'SPY211129C00473000', 'SPY211129C00474000', 'SPY211129C00475000', 'SPY211129C00476000', 'SPY211129C00477000', 'SPY211129C00478000', 'SPY211129C00479000', 'SPY211129C00480000', 'SPY211129C00481000', 'SPY211129C00482000', 'SPY211129C00483000', 'SPY211129C00484000', 'SPY211129C00485000', 'SPY211129C00486000', 'SPY211129C00487000', 'SPY211129C00488000', 'SPY211129C00489000', 'SPY211129C00490000', 'SPY211129C00491000', 'SPY211129C00492000', 'SPY211129C00493000', 'SPY211129C00494000', 'SPY211129C00495000', 'SPY211129C00496000', 'SPY211129C00497000', 'SPY211129C00498000', 'SPY211129C00499000', 'SPY211129C00500000', 'SPY211129C00501000', 'SPY211129C00502000', 'SPY211129C00503000', 'SPY211129C00504000', 'SPY211129C00505000', 'SPY211129C00506000', 'SPY211129C00507000', 'SPY211129C00508000', 'SPY211129C00510000', 'SPY211129C00512000', 'SPY211129C00516000', 'SPY211129C00520000', 'SPY211129C00530000', 'SPY211129C00540000', 'SPY211129C00550000', 'SPY211129C00560000'], 'Strike': ['320.0', '345.0', '355.0', '365.0', '370.0', '385.0', '395.0', '400.0', '405.0', '410.0', '412.0', '413.0', '414.0', '415.0', '416.0', '418.0', '419.0', '420.0', '421.0', '422.0', '423.0', '425.0', '426.0', '428.0', '429.0', '430.0', '431.0', '432.0', '433.0', '434.0', '435.0', '436.0', '437.0', '438.0', '439.0', '440.0', '441.0', '442.0', '443.0', '444.0', '445.0', '446.0', '447.0', '448.0', '449.0', '450.0', '451.0', '452.0', '453.0', '454.0', '455.0', '456.0', '457.0', '458.0', '459.0', '460.0', '461.0', '462.0', '463.0', '464.0', '465.0', '466.0', '467.0', '468.0', '469.0', '470.0', '471.0', '472.0', '473.0', '474.0', '475.0', '476.0', '477.0', '478.0', '479.0', '480.0', '481.0', '482.0', '483.0', '484.0', '485.0', '486.0', '487.0', '488.0', '489.0', '490.0', '491.0', '492.0', '493.0', '494.0', '495.0', '496.0', '497.0', '498.0', '499.0', '500.0', '501.0', '502.0', '503.0', '504.0', '505.0', '506.0', '507.0', '508.0', '510.0', '512.0', '516.0', '520.0', '530.0', '540.0', '550.0', '560.0'], 'Date:': ['2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-29'], 'Last:': ['147.91', '124.82', '114.47', '103.03', ' 88.80', ' 83.05', ' 72.75', ' 58.65', ' 57.65', ' 58.58', ' 51.00', ' 55.69', ' 52.96', ' 52.98', ' 52.10', ' 50.01', ' 48.30', ' 38.15', ' 39.71', ' 45.48', ' 36.15', ' 43.64', ' 33.07', ' 31.74', ' 39.62', ' 35.45', ' 36.01', ' 34.92', ' 36.03', ' 27.37', ' 28.93', ' 24.68', ' 23.39', ' 21.88', ' 20.95', ' 18.74', ' 18.67', ' 17.01', ' 17.94', ' 14.80', ' 14.14', ' 15.34', ' 14.59', ' 11.58', ' 10.23', ' 9.00', ' 8.56', ' 8.02', ' 7.52', ' 6.11', ' 5.40', ' 4.48', ' 3.73', ' 3.24', ' 2.72', ' 2.16', ' 1.73', ' 1.33', ' 1.02', ' 0.71', ' 0.55', ' 0.42', ' 0.26', ' 0.23', ' 0.13', ' 0.11', ' 0.06', ' 0.05', ' 0.06', ' 0.03', ' 0.03', ' 0.03', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.02', ' 0.02', ' 0.02', ' 0.01', ' 0.02', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.03', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.03', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01'], 'Bid:': ['135.83', '111.54', '101.51', ' 91.56', ' 86.56', ' 71.59', ' 61.61', ' 56.62', ' 52.05', ' 46.67', ' 45.40', ' 44.53', ' 43.53', ' 41.66', ' 40.66', ' 38.67', ' 38.57', ' 37.57', ' 36.15', ' 34.74', ' 33.75', ' 31.75', ' 31.20', ' 28.82', ' 27.79', ' 27.68', ' 25.86', ' 25.29', ' 24.62', ' 22.89', ' 21.96', ' 21.40', ' 19.98', ' 19.02', ' 18.91', ' 17.12', ' 16.16', ' 16.06', ' 15.13', ' 13.36', ' 12.46', ' 11.76', ' 10.84', ' 9.96', ' 9.45', ' 8.31', ' 7.49', ' 6.69', ' 6.56', ' 5.16', ' 5.02', ' 3.78', ' 3.69', ' 3.01', ' 2.63', ' 2.11', ' 1.70', ' 1.32', ' 0.96', ' 0.71', ' 0.51', ' 0.34', ' 0.24', ' 0.19', ' 0.10', ' 0.09', ' 0.05', ' 0.05', ' 0.03', ' 0.03', ' 0.02', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.00', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00'], 'Ask:': ['139.27', '113.67', '103.64', ' 93.65', ' 88.69', ' 73.71', ' 63.73', ' 58.00', ' 53.76', ' 48.77', ' 45.94', ' 44.89', ' 43.90', ' 43.77', ' 42.79', ' 39.99', ' 38.94', ' 37.94', ' 37.82', ' 36.87', ' 35.40', ' 33.16', ' 32.43', ' 30.46', ' 29.93', ' 28.05', ' 27.97', ' 26.99', ' 25.16', ' 24.55', ' 24.02', ' 22.59', ' 22.06', ' 20.66', ' 19.28', ' 19.14', ' 17.78', ' 16.43', ' 15.49', ' 14.70', ' 14.45', ' 13.08', ' 11.96', ' 11.54', ' 10.39', ' 9.51', ' 8.49', ' 7.67', ' 6.77', ' 6.53', ' 5.43', ' 5.11', ' 4.00', ' 3.84', ' 2.76', ' 2.28', ' 1.74', ' 1.35', ' 1.16', ' 0.81', ' 0.65', ' 0.42', ' 0.31', ' 0.23', ' 0.18', ' 0.12', ' 0.10', ' 0.09', ' 0.07', ' 0.05', ' 0.04', ' 0.04', ' 0.03', ' 0.02', ' 0.02', ' 0.02', ' 0.01', ' 0.02', ' 0.02', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.02', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.03', ' 0.03', ' 0.03', ' 0.03', ' 0.01', ' 0.03', ' 0.03', ' 0.01', ' 0.03', ' 0.01', ' 0.01', ' 0.03', ' 0.03', ' 0.03', ' 0.01'], 'Volume:': ['No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible', 'No Volume Availible'], 'Open Interest:': [' 20', ' 24', ' 34', ' 0', ' 2', ' 24', ' 2', ' 3', ' 5', ' 14', ' 1', ' 25', ' 5', '508', ' 7', ' 1', ' 24', ' 18', ' 10', ' 1', ' 0', ' 12', ' 29', ' 0', ' 10', ' 33', ' 7', ' 14', ' 6', ' 13', '136', ' 8', ' 4', ' 50', ' 4', ' 79', ' 75', ' 9', '126', '200', '101', ' 45', '134', ' 79', '119', '555', ' 36', '230', ' 46', '238', '527', '374', '408', '747', '327', '016', '429', '550', '972', '649', '268', '511', '655', '193', '463', '714', '312', '212', '165', '255', '202', '445', '898', '903', '302', '989', '137', '163', '744', '718', '420', '117', '345', '941', '312', '659', '168', '177', '222', '231', '922', '747', '811', '263', '176', '326', '215', '110', '150', '612', '858', '486', ' 24', ' 56', '733', ' 6', '700', '626', '453', '295', ' 0', ' 43'], 'Implied Volatility:': ['312.30', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 25.00', ' 46.09', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 46.09', ' 0.00', ' 46.58', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 45.80', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 45.22', ' 30.76', ' 0.00', ' 39.75', ' 33.94', ' 33.89', ' 30.86', ' 31.25', ' 29.83', ' 36.69', ' 31.89', ' 35.82', ' 30.42', ' 34.82', ' 28.96', ' 28.81', ' 27.39', ' 26.91', ' 28.17', ' 26.81', ' 27.34', ' 26.05', ' 26.17', ' 26.42', ' 27.00', ' 26.76', ' 27.74', ' 29.00', ' 29.49', ' 29.69', ' 30.27', ' 31.84', ' 32.23', ' 32.03', ' 33.59', ' 34.77', ' 33.59', ' 37.89', ' 39.06', ' 37.50', ' 39.06', ' 43.36', ' 41.41', ' 42.97', ' 43.75', ' 45.31', ' 46.88', ' 47.66', ' 49.22', ' 50.00', ' 51.56', ' 50.00', ' 50.00', ' 51.56', ' 53.13', ' 54.69', ' 56.25', ' 62.50', ' 64.06', ' 64.84', ' 66.41', ' 60.94', ' 68.75', ' 70.31', ' 65.63', ' 75.00', ' 71.88', ' 76.56', ' 95.31', '107.03', '117.19', '118.75']}
pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

and I am getting the error:

```
C:\Users\USR\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14904/1374576305.py in <module>
----> 1 pd.DataFrame(dict)

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'
```

I get a similar error when I try using `pd.read_html` or basically `pd.anything`.

Comment: Can you try execute `pd` alone?

Comment: yes I get: <module 'pandas' (namespace)>

Comment: Restart the Jupyter Kernel. It may work.

Comment: Don't not use built-in functions as variables (even in examples) `dict`, because it will break things.

Comment: `<module 'pandas' (namespace)>` means that Python found at least one folder named `pandas` when it tried to look for something named `pandas` to import, but it did *not* find an actual, intact Pandas installation. It either found a seriously damaged Pandas installation, or something that was never Pandas at all.

Comment: Do you have any saved files that you named pandas.py? If so, rename them.

Comment: This kind of output suggests that you may have directly modified your Pandas library files, or placed your own code inside your Pandas install directory. Don't do those things.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't named anything pandas.py nor have I(at least intentionally) put any files in pandas folder. So can anyone kindly guide me towards a solution?

Comment: Well reinstalling Anaconda seems to have fixed the issue.